# Filter function will not delete my empty rows - Google App Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I want to import rows from one google sheet to the other, however source sheet imports a number of empty rows. Now I use a filter function to get rid of these rows but they will not disappear, can anyone tell me why?

```
var a = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url").getSheetByName("Admin Use Only").getRange(4,1,6,21).getValues();

  var b = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Credit_Detail'); 

  b.getRange(b.getLastRow() +1, 1, a.length,21).setValues(a);

  //filter function below:

  var otarget=b.getRange(2,1,b.getLastRow()-1, 26).getValues();

  var data=otarget.filter(function(r){

    return !r.every(function(cell){

    return cell === "";});

  });

  Logger.log(data);

  b.getRange("A2:Z").clearContent();

  b.getRange(3,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Comment: please fix your code snippets it looks broken.

Comment: what is the content of `otarget` before filter ?

Comment: May be every cell is not equal to `""`

Comment: Hi @JulienBarrois and @TheMaster, thanks for the concern. If I check the 5 last rows of otarget: `var check=b.getRange(b.getLastRow()-5,1,5,26).getValues();` and then I `Logger.log(check)`   I get the three last rows with empty spaces: [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , , , , ,  ,  , , , , , , , , , , ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , , , , ,  ,  , , , , , , , , , , ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , , , , ,  ,  , , , , , , , , , , ]] But then maybe @TheMaster you must be right as I see that in between "," some have two spaces instead of one ...

Comment: try `cell.trim() === ""` or `cell === " "` if you're sure only 1 whitespace means empty

Answer (score 0):

here's how I would do it. First, create an variable to store the array of the source. then run a for loop scanning the first column for empties. something like: for (var i = 0, i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i][0] != '') { XXXX } }

XXXX means that you can either put a code to create a new set of array which can be passed to the target sheet at once or use append row to transfer non blank rows to the target sheet one by one.

Note: Creating a new array to store non-empty rows would speedup the execution time if you are dealing with large data, thousands of rows.